# How to distribute the load efficiently with Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

**Business case** : I am trying to automate a production flow to replace humans with automation.I receive many triggers from an application on a given day at various intervals and as soon as i get the trigger, scripts should start running automatically.I have 80 nodes(in 80 machines) configured to a Selenium hub.

**Scenario :** Trigger 1 should execute **script 1** in one of the free node.
           Trigger 2 should execute script 2 in one of the free node.
           Trigger 3 should execute script 3 in one of the free node.
           Trigger 4 should execute **script 1** in one of the free node.

In the above scenario script 1 will always get executed in one particular machines only.This is because it's mandatory to specify remote host url while creating a remote web driver object.So if i get two trigger to execute script 1 at the same time then the execution will happen sequentially in the same machine though i have many machines sitting idle.Parallel execution is not the ideal choice here as  i get triggers to start 50-60 executions of the same script at the same time.

**Problem statement :** I am not able to efficiently distribute the load across the free machines.

Is it a limitation of selenium grid?Is there any better way to manage the load distribution?Is it possible to create remote webdriver without specifying the node url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the above scenario script 1 will always get executed in one
>   particular machines only.This is because it's mandatory to specify
>   remote host url while creating a remote web driver object.So if i get
>   two trigger to execute script 1 at the same time then the execution
>   will happen sequentially in the same machine though i have many
>   machines sitting idle.Parallel execution is not the ideal choice here
>   as i get triggers to start 50-60 executions of the same script at the
>   same time.

The Grid was built to ensure that the distribution happens properly and your tests don't have to figure this out. How are you instantiating your `RemoteWebDriver` ? What URL are you passing to it ? You should be passing in the Grid Hub's URL and NOT the node's URL.

As long as your tests are confining themselves to the browser flavor alone in the `DesiredCapabilities` the Hub is going to be able to distribute the tests evenly across all the nodes. If you include `PLATFORM` also into the equation, then the number of nodes that fit the match will be reduced. In either case, you would need to include the following additional details for your problem to get a specific answer :

1. How are you starting your nodes ? [ Is there any node configuration JSON involved ? ]
2. How are you instantiating your `RemoteWebDriver`

Comment: I am starting the node manually using command "java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0.jar -role node -hub http://<IP of hub>:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=firefox,maxInstances=1 -maxSession 1".I am able to invoke script in remote machine when the url of the node is passed to remote web driver object.However if the url of the hub is passed then i am getting the below error

Comment: Jan 30, 2017 10:12:55 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
Jan 30, 2017 10:12:55 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Falling back to original OSS JSON Wire Protocol.
Jan 30, 2017 10:12:55 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Falling back to straight W3C remote end connection

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{marionette=true, browserName=firefox, version=48.0.1, platform=WINDOWS}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
Build info: version: '3.0.0', revision: '350cf60', time: '2016-10-13 10:48:16 -0700'
System info: host: '<host name>', ip: '<ip of hub>', os.name: 'Windows Server 2012 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver

Comment: Simple script to instantiate remote webdriver is give below.System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:/grid/geckodriver.exe");   
   DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities("firefox", "48.0.1", Platform.ANY);
   capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);      
   RemoteWebDriver driver =new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("<ip of hub>:4444/wd/hub"),capabilities);   
   driver.get("myurl");

Comment: @SonaShetty - The Grid is basically telling you that it doesnt have any nodes that can support automation for Firefox version 48.0.1 (which is what you have asked for in your DesiredCapabilities). Please remove the firefox version and try again.

PS : You might want to include all the commands, logs and the java code that u used to create RemoteWEbDriver in your original question itself via an update rather than as comments.

Comment: Thanks.Script is working after removing browser version from Capabilities API

Answer (score -1):

When using Selenium Grid a Hub is setup to which the physical machines register themselves with specific capabilities. For example a Mac will register itself as a Mac with Safari. A linux Machine as such with FireFox and a Windows machine as a IE capable machine.

In your test you connect to the HUB and request a connection to a machine with specific capabilities. The hub then replies with the address of an available machine to which the script then connects. This is the only role the Hub plays and as such it should be exactly what you are looking for.

Walk through the example on the [Selenium HQ](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp) site and it should clarify it for you. This example can be run on a single machine, but ideally it would be good to split it across several.